# Mocking HTTPResponse in a unit test

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, mocking, httpresponse

I'm trying to create unit tests for some legacy code .
One of the classes that I have to test is called FileDownloader which has just the following one method :

```
public void Transmit(string fileName, HttpResponse response, DownloadFileType fileType, byte[] content)
{
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.ContentType = "application/xls";
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(fileName));
    response.BinaryWrite(content);
    response.End();
    response.Flush();
}
```

I'm not allowed to refactor this code ( which would have been ideal ! ).

To test this I decided to create a fake HttpContext based on the article below

[Click this](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/aanttila/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=552eb137-35b0-44f9-bee8-641e08159e2b&ID=27&Web=f31077d6-bea7-416f-82e9-e4103a9c0670)

With this I'm able to get a fake HttpContext during my test execution , however there are issues with faking the HttpResponse .

Here's how my test looks like :

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    mocks = new MockRepository();            
    FakeHttpContext.CreateFakeHttpContext();
}

[Test]
public void ShouldTransmitHttpResponseInTheSpecifiedFormat()
{
    FileDownloader downloader = new FileDownloader();
    string path = "..\\..\\Fakes\\DummyDownloadReportsTemplate.xls";
    byte[] bytes = ReadByteArrayFromFile(path);
    downloader.Transmit("test.xls", new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()), DownloadFileType.Excel, bytes);
}
```

I'm passing a custom created HTTPResponse object to the method.
This throws the following exception when it hits the "response.BinaryWrite(content)" line :

System.Web.HttpException : OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.

I'm not sure what exactly should I be asserting here .. hence there no asserts in the test.
Is this the correct way to test this method ... any ideas . please advise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Another way of testing it is using abstract base classes like HttpContextBase, HttpResponseBase, etc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase(v=VS.90).aspx

HttpContextBase is a part of .NET 3.5 SP1, .NET 4.0 and can be installed as a separate package for .NET 2.0.
When I was testing uploading/downloading handlers that feature had appeared a remedy for me :-).

Usage is simple. This method will be covered with test.

```
public void Transmit(string fileName, HttpResponseBase response, DownloadFileType fileType, byte[] content)
{
...
// main logic.
...
}
```

For the real context you can just create a stub and delegate to the testable method, like:

```
public void Transmit(string fileName, HttpResponse response, DownloadFileType fileType, byte[] content)
{
   var requestWrapper = new HttpResponseWrapper(response);
   this.Transmit(fileName, requestWrapper, fileType, content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project we are successly using HttpSimulator for such purposes:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx

Comment: Thanks .. I've had a look at the HttpSimulator .. but I still can't follow how to create a fake HttpResponse ... could you please elaborate a bit  .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all ..
Actually I should have been using the Response of the fake HttpContext that
I had created .. instead of creating a new Response object :

```
 downloader.Transmit("test.xls", HttpContext.Current.Response, DownloadFileType.Excel, bytes);
```

this works !!!!